# How to fetch linked LiveData in Room LiveData?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

I have few linked tables (entities):

```
@Entity(
        tableName = L.TABLE_NAME,
        foreignKeys = [
            ForeignKey(
                    entity = S::class,
                    parentColumns = [KeyEntity.K_ID],
                    childColumns = [L.K_S_ID],
                    onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
                    onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE),
            ForeignKey(entity = T::class,
                    parentColumns = [KeyEntity.K_ID],
                    childColumns = [L.K_T_ID],
                    onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
                    onDelete = ForeignKey.SET_NULL
            )
        ]
)
class L(
        id: Int = INVALID_ID,

        @ColumnInfo(name = K_S_ID, index = true)
        var sId: Int = INVALID_ID,

        @ColumnInfo(name = K_T_ID, index = true)
        var tId: Int? = null
) : KeyEntity(id)

@Entity(tableName = S.TABLE_NAME)
class S(
        id: Int = INVALID_ID,
        /* Other fields */
) : KeyEntity(id)

@Entity(tableName = T.TABLE_NAME)
class T(
        id: Int = INVALID_ID,
        /* Other fields */
) : KeyEntity(id)
```

I need to get all L-entites and their linked (by foreign key) S- and T-entities to build items for my adapter. Now, I have the next function:

```
fun fetch(): LiveData<MutableList<LAdapter.LItem>> {
    return Transformations.map(db.lDao().getLs()) {
        val lItems = mutableListOf<LAdapter.LItem>()
        it.forEach { l ->
            lItems.add(LAdapter.LItem(
                    s = "S text", // db.sDao().getS(l.sId)/../.name
                    t = "T text" // db.tDao().getT(l.tId)/../.name
            ))
        }
        lItems
    }
}
```

The problem is that `getS()` and `getT()` return `LiveData<S>` and `LiveData<T>` and I can't get how to combine all these three `LiveData`s together. And it also looks stupidly to write for each DAO-method two variant with `LiveData` and not-`LiveData`.

What's right way to get few linked entities in Room when you are using `LiveData`?

Comment: why do you wants LiveData return type in db.rDao().getR()? You can return only REntity.

Comment: @AmitTiwary I just want to get few linked entities by foreign keys. But I didn't find in official doc how to make it.

Comment: can you add your entities and also describe what you want to do exactly so that we can help you easily.

Comment: @AmitTiwary, I have updated my question